# Joing multiple Linq Clauses

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Linq queries that work:

- The first retrieves 10,000 records:

```
     List<UserModel> userslist2 = 
     (from USZipCode in _db.USZipCodes                     
     where SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(.....) <= 25
     join User in _db.Users on USZipCode.ZipCode equals User.ZipCode
     select User).Take(10000).ToList();
```

- The uses the results of first query to do some more search and obtain 800 records. Below Query also works:

```
    var x = (from user in userslist2
             where (user.Ethnicity == Ethnicity) &&
             (user.Sex == Gender) &&
             (user.HasProfilePhoto == HasProfilePic) 
            select new SearchResultsViewModel
            {
              _userid = user.UserID,
              _username = user.UserName,                                  
              _sex = user.Sex,
              _city = user.City,
              _state = user.State,
            }).Take(800).ToList();
```

I want to combine the two clauses and I came up with the following, but it is giving errors (won't compile):

```
var x = (from user in 
        (from USZipCode in _db.USZipCodes                     
         where SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(.....) <= 25
         join User in _db.Users on USZipCode.ZipCode equals User.ZipCode
         select User).Take(10000).ToList().Where( user.Ethnicity == Ethnicity &&
                                                  user.Sex == Gender &&
                                                  user.HasProfilePhoto == HasProfilePic) 
        select new SearchResultsViewModel
        {
          _userid = user.UserID,
          _username = user.UserName,                                  
          _sex = user.Sex,
          _city = user.City,
          _state = user.State,
        }).Take(800).ToList();
```

Comment: "*but it is giving errors*" -- **what** errors?

Comment: FYI instead of `SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(.....) <= 25` you could do `..... <= 625` or even `.... <= 25 * 25` to point out that it's 25 squared.

Comment: There is also the question as to why you want to do this. From your combined query above you are making two trips to the server anyway with the `.ToList()` and it may be easier to debug with the two separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not well asked, but to combine two LINQ queries you can... well, combine two LINQ queries:

```cs
var userslistQuery = 
     (from USZipCode in _db.USZipCodes                     
     where SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(.....) <= 25
     join User in _db.Users on USZipCode.ZipCode equals User.ZipCode
     select User).Take(10000);

var x = (from user in userslistQuery 
             where (user.Ethnicity == Ethnicity) &&
             (user.Sex == Gender) &&
             (user.HasProfilePhoto == HasProfilePic) 
            select new SearchResultsViewModel
            {
              _userid = user.UserID,
              _username = user.UserName,                                  
              _sex = user.Sex,
              _city = user.City,
              _state = user.State,
            }).Take(800).ToList();
```

Just use the query, not the resultant `List`.